# Improving Efficiency of Random Walker

Tags: python, performance

I'm seeing a web course of computational statistics, the first project consists of a random walker, the implementation I have done works as intended:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WALKER_STEPS: int = 5_000

# random orientation converted from degrees to radians
directions: np.array = rd.uniform(low=0, high=360, size=WALKER_STEPS) * np.pi / 180

x: list = [0]
y: list = [0]
idx: int = 0
for rad in directions:
    # updates the positions of the walker
    x.append(x[idx] + np.cos(rad))
    y.append(y[idx] + np.sin(rad))
    idx += 1

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I don't like the way I'm adding new elements to the lists `x, y` and I think that there's a more elegant way to do it.

Here a image of the result:

[image: Execution of Random Walk Algorithm]

Note: I didn't do an abstraction because the exercise in small.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to improve performance here? I tested the code, and running 5000 iterations only takes around 20ms which feels pretty fast. Is it just for personal interest, or is there some requirement?

Comment: @maxb It's personal interest, I'm near to get my degree (I hope) and I feel quite nervious regarding the "real world" (my work after getting a job). I feel like I haven't learned well in college so I'm doing web courses.

Comment: I get that feeling. While this might wander a bit off topic, I'll say that studying to become a programmer/software engineer and actually working as one are two very different things. However, you'll learn a ton of stuff at your first job, so your days of learning definitely don't end when you get your degree. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.cumsum()`

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
WALKER_STEPS: int = 5_000

# random orientation converted from degrees to radians
directions: np.array = rd.uniform(low=0, high=360, size=WALKER_STEPS) * np.pi / 180

x = np.cos(directions).cumsum()
y = np.sin(directions).cumsum()

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a really great improvement, but not strictly equal to the original code since it doesn't add the `0` value at the start of the array. You could just do something like `x = np.empty(WALKER_STEPS+1); y = np.empty(WALKER_STEPS+1); x[0] = 0; y[0] = 0; x[1:] = np.cos(directions).cumsum(); y[1:] = np.sin(directions).cumsum()` (sorry for the clutter) which exactly reproduces the original code but keeps the performance of your solution.